# Offset problem when using ctypes in Python 2

Tags: python, bitmap, header, ctypes, offset

I am trying to read the headers of a small bitmap ("test1.bmp"). I quickly found the structure. But when I try to implement it in Python 2.7 using Structure from ctypes, something strange happens: The offset of the ,,size"-ulong is moved forward by 2 bytes. (see below)

```
>>> BMPHeader.size
<Field type=c_ulong, ofs=4, size=4>
```

,,ofs" should be 2, because ,,size" comes after the ,,id"-char*2. This generates an error:

```
ValueError: Buffer size too small (14 instead of at least 16 bytes)
```

What shifts the ,,size"-offset by 2 bytes?

Here's my code:

```
from ctypes import *

filename = "test1.bmp"
data     = None

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    data = file.read()

class BMPHeader(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("id",       c_char * 2),
        ("size",     c_ulong),
        ("reserved", c_ulong),
        ("offset",   c_ulong)]

    def __new__(self, data_buffer=None):
        return self.from_buffer_copy(data_buffer)

    def __init__(self, data_buffer):
        pass

header = BMPHeader(data[:14])
```

P.S.: Please excuse my english (not native). I'm also just a beginner when working with headers etc., so it's quite possible it's just my bad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures have padding by default for alignment purposes. In your case, it's adding 2 bytes of padding between `id` and `size`. Since you're trying to read a file in that doesn't have any padding, you need to turn it off in your structure. Do this by adding `_pack_ = 1` under `class BMPHeader(Structure):`.